# Не находится удаленные файлы вирусом шифровальщиком wanadecryptor 2.0

Tags: шифрование, восстановление, wannacry

Два диска локальных на которых было много вордовских доккментов.  Вирус все зашифровал. Сканирую множеством программ для восстановления удаленных файлов и результат один и тот же.  На одном диске все файлы и папки восстанавливаются. На другом пусто,  как будто этих файлов не было вообще,  ни следа. Не мог же вирус на другом диске как то по другому от них избавиться.  Например зашифровать и в этом же файле сохранить.  На сколько я знаю если в файл что то добавить он сохраняется на жестком диске в новом месте. Диск у меня один и он магнитный,  не ssd.  Сам жесткий занят был на  10 процентов и попытки восстановления предпринимались сразу же.  Не пойму как можно быть так что от пары сотен файлов не осталось и следа?

Comment: В вирусе запросто могут быть баги, почему бы и нет.

Comment: Один и тот же вирус на многих компах. Какие то локальные диски восстанавливаются, какие то нет.  Что он может сделать такое что файл не будет найдет прогой для восстановления?

Comment: "Прога для восстановления" в целом вещь ненадёжная, поскольку ищет что-то в пространстве, которое числится свободным для файловой системы. Файловая система может использовать это место по своему усмотрению как угодно. Если система активно создаёт и удаляет файлы, что во время работы шифровымогателя типично, на восстановление из незанятого места можно не рассчитывать: оно будет повторно использоваться для других файлов. Да и шифровальщик теоретически может использовать secure erase для файлов: записывать мусор поверх их содержимого по несколько раз перед удалением. Всё плохо.

Comment: Вирус всего один. На оба локальных диска.  На одном он всё восстановил,  их 300 документов всё на месте.  Во вторых вирус  не решает в каком месте в жестком диске запишется мусорный файл или новый файл. А жесткий на 90 процентов был пустой.  Ну не мог он переписать сверху другие файлы и удалить всё  в Ноль.  Хоть один файл пусть даже с иероглифами да сохранился бы. Точно такая же ситуация на серверном компе,  Там тоже один локальный диск как будто не имел никаких файлов.

Comment: Хм.. Удаление теневых копий?

Answer (score 1):

На хабре писали, что он активно записывал на диск мусор - как раз для того, чтобы уменьшить шансы на восстановление удалённых файлов. Видимо, ему это удалось.

Comment: возможно, но в этом случае я должен увидеть этот мусор. А его я не вижу. Или же это тупо набор байтов без всяких разрешений, который у программ восстановления ни с чем не ассоциируется.